# jquery .toggleClass on click using multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle the scrollbar of the `<html>` tag using jquery.

I want the scrollbar to disappear when i click on button #foo, and i want it to reappear when i click on #bar1.

```js
$('#foo').click(function() {
  $('html').toggleClass("hidescroll");
});
$('#bar1').click(function() {
  $('html').toggleClass("hidescroll");
});
```

```css
.hidescroll{
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">foo</div>
<div id="bar1">bar1</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

it disappears when i click on #foo, but it doesnt reappear on #bar1, however it reappears when #foo is clicked again.

Comment: What is CSS for `.hidescroll`

Comment: can you make a js fiddle. according to your code it will work no issues

Comment: It does work -> https://jsfiddle.net/fyedavht/. Do you definitely have same ids of `foo` and `bar1` in your html?

Comment: its working bro

Comment: your example clearly works here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this...use add and removeClass instead of toggleClass...

```js
$('#foo').click(function() {
  $('html').addClass("hidescroll");
});

$('#bar1').click(function() {
  $('html').removeClass("hidescroll");
});
```

```css
.hidescroll {
  overflow:hidden;
}
#main {
  width:100%;
  height:2000px;
  float:left;
}
#foo {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-right:15px;
}
#bar1 {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked using `overflow: hidden` instead of `overflow-y: hidden`. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#foo, #bar1")
```

is the selector you're looking for.

Snippet :

```js
$('#foo, #bar1').click(function() {
  $('html').toggleClass("hidescroll");
});
```

```css
.hidescroll {
  overflow:hidden;
}
#main {
  width:100%;
  height:2000px;
  float:left;
}
#foo {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-right:15px;
}
#bar1 {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative

```
bar =v=> $('html').css('overflow',v)
$('#foo').click(()=> bar('hidden'))
$('#bar1').click(()=> bar('scroll'))
```